# How do I know if a method was called server-side or client-side (from the server)?

Tags: meteor

In my Meteor app, I have a method defined on the server as follows:

```
/* global Meteor */
Meteor.methods({
    notifyRequestRejected: function (username, reason) {
        if (!Meteor.userId()) {
            throw new Meteor.Error(403, 'Access denied');
        }
        return Meteor.http.post('…');
    }
});
```

As I only want authenticated users and my server-side (trusted) code to be able to call the method, *how can I check if the method was called server-side or client-side?* Is there something like `this.calledFromServer` for methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to check if a method call was made server-side or client-side by checking the `this.connection` property.

If it is not null, then it means that the method was called from the client-side.

So, to make sure that the caller is either an authenticated user or some server-side code, use:

```
Meteor.methods({
    notifyRequestRejected: function (username, reason) {
        if (!Meteor.userId() && this.connection) {
            throw new Meteor.Error(403, 'Access denied');
        }
        // etc.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `this.isSimulation` or `Meteor.isClient` to detect the execution of a client-side stub.

You can negate these expressions to detect server-side environment or use `Meteor.isServer`.